# Why the progress bar does not advance or move in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I would like you to help me to understand why when I calculate the information in this shiny, the progress bar does not advance or go up indicating when it is still to finish the calculation done.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(progressr)
library(lavaan)

#Example of data to load
df1 <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jventural/Download/main/df1.csv", sep = ";")

#ui.r
ui <- fluidPage(
  # 
  sidebarLayout(
    # Main panel ----------------
    sidebarPanel(
      sidebarMenu( 
                   menuItem("Calculadora", tabName = "sect_a")
                
      )
    ),

    mainPanel(
        # Calculator ----------
        tabItem(
          tabName = "sect_a",
          tabsetPanel(
            id="tabA",
            type = "tabs",
            tabPanel("Calculando omega",
                     fileInput("datafile", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
                     
                     actionButton(inputId = "click1", "Calcular"),
                     fluidPage(
                       HTML("<b> Nota: </b> El nombre de los items debe ser: Item1, Item2... etc")
                     )
            ),
            tabPanel("Output", tableOutput("modifiedData")
            ))
        )
        
    )
  )
)

#server.r


server = function(input, output) {
  
  # Calculadora -----------
  result = eventReactive(list(input$datafile, input$click1),
                         {
                           req(input$click1)
                           raw_df <- read.csv(input$datafile$datapath, sep=";")
                           
                           
                           IC <- 
                             MBESS::ci.reliability(data = raw_df %>% select(starts_with("Item")), N = nrow(raw_df), type = "categorical", interval.type = "perc", B = 10)
                    
                           
                         })
  
  output$modifiedData = renderTable({
    withProgress(message = 'Calculando',
                 detail = 'Espera un momento...', value = 0, {
                   result()
                 })
    result()
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I remain attentive to your suggestions

I am posting the codes so that you can see what I have been trying to do.

Comment: Please google on how `incProgress()` is used `withProgress()`.

Comment: YBS thanks for the information, but I just require more support than that. Maybe how could I modify the code.